# use find command in conjunction with string replacement

Tags: bash

In bash, one can do something like this in a for loop to, say, convert pdf files in a directory to pngs systematically.

```
for file in $(ls .)
do
  convert ${file} ${file/.pdf/.png}
done
```

Note here that bash string replacement syntax allows for concise code.

When I tried the same with `find` I'm hopelessly stuck. Is there any way of implementing this with `find` in conjunction with (similar) string replacement syntax? Of course one can do this for example like this

`find . | sed "s/\.pdf//" | xargs -i convert {}.pdf {}.png`

but I like the idea of being able to use (something like bash) string replacement syntax together with `find -exec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the shell.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'convert "$1" "${1/.pdf/.png}"' -- {} \;
```

You can export a function for readability and correctness.

```
func() {
   convert "$1" "${1/.pdf/.png}"
}
export -f func
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'func "$@"' -- {} \;
```

Finally, you can use xargs to parallelize workflow.

```
func() {
   convert "$1" "${1/.pdf/.png}"
}
export -f func
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -P$(nproc) -0n1 bash -c 'func "$@"' --
```

Check your script with shellcheck.